# What do you name tables that have both a class and an instance version?

Tags: database, naming-conventions

For example, I have a vehicle class (id, year, make, model) and a vehicle instance (id, vehicle_id, vin). Can't figure out what to name them to differentiate the two. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would just call it what it is, which is a model year:

```
VehicleModel

Vehicle
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use vehicle_model for the "class" table, and vehicle for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

What about `VehicleTypes` for the class and `Vehicles` for the instances?

Comment: I thought of that at first, then I thought, vehicle type is more like truck, car, suv, motorcycle, etc... It seems like a VehicleModel attribute.